# Does Python syntax prevent me from creating this list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, list-comprehension

I am trying to recreate a for loop (A) into a list comprehension. I think the problem here is that there are too many functions that need to be done to **ni**, namely squaring it and then making sure it is an integer before appending onto **nn** .

The list comprehension (B) is an attempt at getting the list comprehension to take a string (m) and square each individual number as an integer. The problem is that it needs to iterate over each number as a string THEN square itself as individual integers.

## A

```
n = str(2002)
nn = []

for x in range(len(n)):
    ni = n[x]
    ns = int(ni)**2
    nn.append(ns)

print(nn)
```

> [4, 0, 0, 4]

## B

```
m = str(9119)

mm = [(int(m[x]))**2 for x in m]
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

This makes me feel like A cannot be done as a list comprehension? Love to see what your thoughts for alternatives and/or straight up solutions are.

Comment: why you do `m[x]`? you are already iterating `for x in m` so just do `int(x)`. converting a loop to a list-comprehension is pretty straightforward and you were very close. Your problem is that you changed your loop. In A you do `for x in range(len(n))` but in B `for x in m`. Either do `int(x)**2 for x in m` or `int(m[x])**2 for x in range(len(m))` but just stick to one...

Comment: Thank you, My confusion was that I didn't know the difference between range() and the list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string as the index!

**Additionally,** you were trying to index the string `m` with the number at each index instead of its index (e.g, you tried to index `m[0]` with `m[9]` instead)

Try using the following instead:

```
m = str(9119)

mm = [int(x)**2 for x in m] #Thanks @Gelineau
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `mm = [(int(x))**2 for x in m]` is even better.

Answer (score 0):

`x` represents each digit in `m`. So you just have to square it

```
mm = [int(x)**2 for x in m]
```